# How can I get many integers from the same text field?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to retrieve several integers from the same text field, but I can't figure out how to do it. Anyone?

Comment: You should add a minimal example: what did you try, what is the content of the `TextField`.

Comment: I'll try to rephrase myself. I'd like to retrive exactly 10 integers from one textfield and add all together. It's quite simple to do this in the console with a for loop. But i just can't figure out how to solve it in FX.

Comment: ...and i'm not sure where to put my example. by answering myself?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a clearer solution.  This will throw and error for incorrect input.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication37 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label info = new Label("Enter some numbers. Each seperated by one space");

        TextField tf = new TextField();
        Label label = new Label();

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Sum Numbers");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {            
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                if(tf.getText().length() > 0)//Only run if the text field is not empty
                {
                    String[] stringOfNumbers = tf.getText().split(" ");//The numbers must be seperated by one space. This get the string of numbers and seperates them based on the space between each numbers

                    //sum up the numbers
                    double sum = 0;
                    for(int i = 0; i < stringOfNumbers.length; i++)
                    {
                        sum = sum + Double.parseDouble(stringOfNumbers[i]);//This sums the numbers and convert the strings to doubles                  
                    }
                    label.setText("The sum equals: " + sum);//This prints the sum of the doubles   
                }
            }
        });

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(info, tf, label, btn);//This adds all the nodes to the VBox

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);//This adds the VBox to the Scene

        primaryStage.setTitle("Sum Numbers");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }    
}
```

> I noticed this question asked to handle integers. In this code change double to int and Double to Integer.

I am adding this solution since your solution did not contain a button

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication37 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label info = new Label("Enter some numbers each seperated by one space");
        Label label = new Label();

        TextField tf = new TextField();
        tf.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            try
            {
                if(newValue.length() > 0)//Only run if the text field is not empty
                {
                    String[] stringOfNumbers = tf.getText().split(" ");//The numbers must be seperated by one space. This get the string of numbers and seperates them based on the space between each numbers

                    //sum up the numbers
                    int sum = 0;
                    for(int i = 0; i < stringOfNumbers.length; i++)
                    {
                        sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(stringOfNumbers[i]);//This sums the numbers and convert the strings to doubles                  
                    }
                    label.setText("The sum equals: " + sum);//This prints the sum of the doubles   
                }    
                else
                {
                    label.setText("");//if no text in textfield set label to empty string
                }
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException ex)
            {
                label.setText("");//any number format error set label to empty string
            }
        });     

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(info, tf, label);//This adds all the nodes to the VBox

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);//This adds the VBox to the Scene

        primaryStage.setTitle("Sum Numbers");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }    
}
```

Comment: I mixed up FX with Swing. It doesn't work the same way.
This is exactly what i wanted. I modified the code a bit to use a text area. Thank you very much!

Comment: If the answer is the solution, you should accept it.